# Can the internal FET be disabled?

Tags: voltage, usb, flash, usb-device, nand

In this [device](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00001979A.pdf), can the internal FET be disabled for the CRD_PWR pin?

Can the CRD_PWR pin be left floating?

Comment: Which particular device of those mentioned in the data sheet?

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand your question

Comment: The data sheet describes 4 chips. Which one are you using?

Comment: USB2244 is the actual device

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: Did you read page 24?

Comment: Yes I did read the page 24. The internal FET can be disabled and be left floating , right? @StainlessSteelRat. But there's no explicit mention that the pin can be left floating. That's why I have this questions. So, if the internal FET be disabled through the register settings mentioned on page 24, then can I leave this pin unconnected?

Comment: As Byran suggests, this question would have to be answered by the manufacturer, unless someone has used the part as you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no explicit mention of it in the data sheet, and you’re best off contacting microchip directly for permission, but the initial state of this pin is off and the maximum ratings make it sound pretty bombproof:
[image: data sheet maximum ratings here]

I would expect this pin to tolerate being floated.

Comment: So, the pin can be left floating?

Comment: @Newbie yeah that’s my expectation. You might want to leave in a test point or smt resistor land just in case the code inside has expectations.